# Required field on Html.TextBoxFor is being ignored for some reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a textbox inside a form be a "required" field on the client side and for some reason it is being ignored.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, "City", new { @class = "d-block" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
</div>
```

I've tried changing it to -

```
@required = "required",
@required = true,
required = true.
```

There is only one form on the view im working on.

I don't want to make the field required on the model, it needs to be done on the client side.

Not sure why this is being ignored, is there something that I am over looking?

Comment: any particular reason you're not using the [Required] data annotation on the model object, and then enabling the built-in client-side validation integration? Why don't you want to do this? You really ought to apply server-side validation as well - otherwise a malicious user could simply manipulate the client-side code (or just use a non-browser client to send the request) and bypass your restriction. If the restriction should only be applied at certain times then you could consider having a different viewmodel for each scenario, or having custom validation rules.

Comment: You should **always** validate on the server-side if you value the integrity of your data. Client-side validation is nice-to-have user-friendly sugar on top, but by itself it doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: Its because the model object can be empty when the entry in the table is initially created. its only required later on for other functionality later on in the app.

Comment: Ok. Well like I said that's a use case for either different viewmodels for inserting and updating (they can share in-common properties via inheritance, to save duplication), or custom data annotations (e.g. via 3rd party nuget packages which introduce annotations such as `RequiredIf` style of rules), so that server-side validation is still implemented in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

can you please add this line in config file and then check...

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with it. That only applies if OP was using MVC's built-in validation tools, which they've explicitly stated they aren't

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

This line is already in my config file.